# Clean string to get Email with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a ruby code that extracts email addresses from a page. my code outputs the email address, but also captures other text as well.

I would like to pull the actual email out of this string. Sometimes, the string will include a mailto, sometimes it will not. I was trying to get the single word that occurs before the @, and anything that comes after the @ by using a split, but I'm having trouble. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
href="mailto:someonesname@domain.rr.com"> |  Email</a></td>
```

Comment: Are you sure *ALL* addresses you encounter will be in that format? Email addresses themselves can be in a very large number of formats.

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
inputstring[/href="[^"]+"/][6 .. -2].gsub("mailto:", "")
```

#### Explanation:

- Grab the href attribute and it's contents
- Remove the `href=` and qoutes
- Remove the `mailto:` if it's there

#### Example:

```
irb(main):021:0> test = "href=\"mailto:francesco@hawaii.rr.com\"> |  Email DuVin</a></td>"
=> "href=\"mailto:francesco@hawaii.rr.com\"> |  Email DuVin</a></td>"
irb(main):022:0> test[/href="[^"]+"/][6 .. -2].gsub("mailto:", "")
=> "francesco@hawaii.rr.com"
irb(main):023:0> test = "href=\"francesco@hawaii.rr.com\"> |  Email DuVin</a></td>"
=> "href=\"francesco@hawaii.rr.com\"> |  Email DuVin</a></td>"
irb(main):024:0> test[/href="[^"]+"/][6 .. -2].gsub("mailto:", "")
=> "francesco@hawaii.rr.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, will this work if there is no mailto in the string?

Comment: Yes this will work if there is a mailto or if there isn't a mailto. See the example in the question, to see how it works. Also if you think this is the correct answer please accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use something prebuilt:

```
require 'uri'

addresses = URI.extract(<<EOT, :mailto)
this is some text. mailto:foo@bar.com and more text
and some more http://foo@bar.com text
href="mailto:someonesname@domain.rr.com"> |  Email</a></td>
EOT
addresses # => ["mailto:foo@bar.com", "mailto:someonesname@domain.rr.com"]
```

[URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract) comes with Ruby, and the pattern used to parse out URIs is well tested. It's not bullet-proof, but it works pretty well. If you're getting false-positives, you can use a `select`, `reject` or `grep` block to filter out the unwanted entries returned.

If you can't count on having `mailto:`, the problem becomes harder, because email addresses aren't simple to parse; There's too much variation to them. The problem is akin to validating an email address using a pattern, because, again, the format for addresses varies too much. "[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)" and "[JavaScript Email Validation when there are (soon to be) 1000's of TLD's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438012/javascript-email-validation-when-there-are-soon-to-be-1000s-of-tlds)" are good reads for more information.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work nicely though won't account for **invalid** email formats - it will simply extract the email address based on your two use cases.

```
string[/[^\"\:](\w+@.*)(?=\")/]
```